# How can I add Force to my object with gravity so that It can travel to Long Distance?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity, rigid-bodies

I am new In Unity and I am Developing one Simple game where Plates are Initiate from One place and It will Destroy on click.
I want to show my plate flying from one place to another place with Gravity.

My code for Plate Initiate is Below..

```
void Update () {

    InitTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    print("InitTimer" +InitTimer);
    if(InitTimer <= 0){
        InitTimer = Random.Range(1f, 2f);
        Instantiate(plate,new Vector3 (range,transform.position.y,transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Can Anyone give me any reference code or any guidance?

I want to fly my every plate In one Direction.

Thank You In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate the plate to a `GameObject` then `AddForce` to it:

```
GameObject plate = Instantiate(plate,new Vector3 (range,transform.position.y,
                   transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

// example of adding force in x axis, change the vector3 however you want
plate.rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Don't forget to add a rigidbody to your prefab.

Comment: Its not Working for Me Plates are not even move with this.

Comment: Now Its working I forgot to Instantiate the plate as game object.Thank You.